# angular error when trying to get piechart working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get [this piechar](http://www.fusioncharts.com/angularjs-charts/#/demos/ex2)t working. 
Here is my code to draw simple piechart

```
<html ng-app="chartApp">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- angular -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

  <!-- fusioncharts core -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>

  <!-- angular plugin -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-fusioncharts.min.js"></script>

  <!-- zune theme -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zune-theme.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var pieChart = angular.module("pieChart", ["ng-fusioncharts"]);

// controller for chart
pieChart.controller("chartController", function($scope) {

  $scope.myDataSource = {
    chart: {
        caption: "Age profile of website visitors",
        subcaption: "Last Year",
        startingangle: "120",
        showlabels: "0",
        showlegend: "1",
        enablemultislicing: "0",
        slicingdistance: "15",
        showpercentvalues: "1",
        showpercentintooltip: "0",
        plottooltext: "Age group : $label Total visit : $datavalue",
        theme: "fint"
    },
    data: [
        {
            label: "Teenage",
            value: "1250400"
        },
        {
            label: "Adult",
            value: "1463300"
        },
        {
            label: "Mid-age",
            value: "1050700"
        },
        {
            label: "Senior",
            value: "491000"
        }
    ]
}});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <center>
      <div ng-controller="chartController">
       <fusioncharts 
    width="600" 
    height="400"
    type="pie3d"
    datasource="{{myDataSource}}"
></fusioncharts>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=chartApp&p1=Error%3…0zc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.1%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `angular.module` is set to "pieChart", but your `ng-app` directive is set to `chartApp` (this directive should be put on `body` instead of `html` also)... so Angular has no idea what to bootstrap. Try using `angular.module("chartApp", ...)` and putting `ng-app` directive on your 'body' tag.